# C++11 chrono:assigning values to time_point objects

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm trying to use chrono to measure time spent by some function, so my code looks like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void doSomething()
{
  //code goes here
}

int main()
{
  chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> start,end;
  start=chrono::system_clock::now;
  doSomething();
  end=chrono::system_clock::now;
}
```

So, basically, i'm following code example from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

The problem is that i have following error at both `start=chrono::system_clock::now` and `end=chrono::system_clock::now`

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 
'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, 
std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >'
and 'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point()noexcept (true) 
{aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,
std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >()noexcept (true)}')
```

I also tried to change `chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> start,end;` to `chrono::system_clock::time_point start,end;`. The error is pretty much the same:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are
'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point 
{aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,
std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >}'
and 'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point()noexcept (true) 
{aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,
std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >()noexcept (true)}')
```

I'm using Qt 5.1.0 (32bit) with MinGW 4.8 32bit as a compiler. I also had to add compiler flag for c++11 support by adding `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11` in my *.pro* file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `()` for `system_clock::now`

```
  chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> start,end;
  start=chrono::system_clock::now(); //<-- Fix

 doSomething();
  end=chrono::system_clock::now();  //<-- Fix
```

Calculate **Elapsed Time** as:

```
  auto duration = end - start;
  std::cout << chrono::duration <double, std::milli> (duration).count()
            << " ms" << std::endl;
```